# How does the Level select work with the game timer?

Tags: ios, prince-of-persia

In *Prince of Persia Retro* for iOS, you are able to select a level from the main screen. I remember the original game had a 60 minute time limit--does selecting a level affect the timer?

Answer (score -1):

In the original DOS version, you could (without activating cheats) skip the first few levels. However, this would set your timer down to 15 minutes, and you could not skip beyond the 4th level.